# Windows keeps storing wrong credentials for onedrive mapped as network drive

Tags: windows-11, onedrive, network-drive, credentials, mapped-drive

I have my onedrive mapped as a network drive with drive letter X:.

The first time I open the drive after a reboot, I get prompted for the login credentials, with the credentials prefilled, just waiting for me to press OK.

[image]

However, these credentials don't work. I need to *manually* remove the domain `MicrosoftAccount\` each time. I then click `Remember my credentials`, and select OK.

[image]

After this, the login succeeds, and I can go on with my work.

However, when I reboot my machine, windows *did not* remember my credentials, and I get the first of the two dialogs again.

**Why is this, and how can I fix it?**

**And, as an additional question: Can I set Windows to automatically login to the drive (i.e. skipping the confirmation screen of the credentials)?**

Comment: Disconnect and reconnect the drive.  During that process you will be provided an option to authenticate automatically as another user.  That is the option you want to use.

Comment: There are a few steps I usually take in this case: 1. sign out of word/excel's account tab and repeat in case another user shows up, all the way until you see the login button. (this is usually enough to get to work). 2. Windows -> Settings -> Accounts -> School or work account, sign out of all those. 3. Go to control panel, credential manager, and delete all entries linked to office. 4. If all fails, there's a location in the registry where office places its references. Delete that entire key. Now it will work for sure.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks. but this didn't work. Still same behaviour

Comment: @LPChip thanks, but this also didn't work. Unless I missed any registy keys. Which registry keys do you mean, specifically?

Comment: Delete this entire key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity\Identities

Comment: Thanks @LPChip, but unfortunately that didn't work either. No matter what I do (even if I follow all your steps), when I reboot, this credential shows up in credential manager: https://i.imgur.com/y3bO4hb.png. I'm gonna see if there's some way to edit the file/location where credential manager pulls that information from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not a direct answer to the problem I had here, I was able to mount my onedrive with [rclone](https://rclone.org/). Running a script that automatically mounts the disk at startup makes my onedrive available automatically on windows explorer, without repeatedly asking for credentials.

```
rclone mount onedrive: X: --network-mode --vfs-cache-mode full
```

An added benefit of this approach is that rclone makes it so that the correct size and usage of the disk is displayed in Windows Explorer (unlike when it is mounted as a network drive the "windows way").

**Note**: To mount a onedrive with rclone on windows, [WinFSP](https://winfsp.dev/) is needed.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to delete the relevant credentials in Credential Manager and then log back in.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, this didn't work. Behaviour is still the same. I made sure to delete all credentials that looked remotely related.